# TypeError: frontModel.find(...).sort(...).limit(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't seem to crack this one.

The frontModel is....

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var frontSchema = new Schema(
    {
        _id: Number, // Current Date/Time when this page is valid 
        content: Array // Array of content
    },
    {
        versionKey: false // Don't want to insert _v in document
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('frontModel', frontSchema, 'front');
```

I want to find the frontpage with the highest `_id` (numeric field in this case)

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let frontModel = require('../models/frontModel');

exports.frontpage = (req) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        return resolve(frontModel.find().sort({ "_id": -1 }).limit(1)(
        ))
    });
};
```

But all I get is :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: frontModel.find(...).sort(...).limit(...) is not a function

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is frontModel? and `find` should take a callback function.

Comment: You hav e not properly imported the `frontModel` .

Comment: sorry I forgot to show the frontModel, but thats not the issue. 
I believe its callback (like @callback says) but I thought I could just return the result in a promise (like I do with aggregates)

Comment: Please import the frontModel properly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the .exec()

After I added that one, everything worked just fine.

```
    frontTable.find().sort( { "_id" : -1 } ).limit(1).exec(
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) { return reject(new Error('ERROR : ' + err)) }
            return resolve(data);
        }
    )
```